# Retrieve name of selected/clicked item of a custom list using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to retrieve the name of selected/clicked item of a custom list using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The "s4-itm-selected" class is applied to any selected list row.

$(".s4-itm-selected") would work in simple situations. If there are multiple list views on a page and you only wish to affect one, you'll want to make the selector more specific.